# Conditional Expectation Problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

An insurance company supposes that the number of accidents that each of its customers will have this year is Poisson distributed, with a mean depending on the customer: the Poisson mean $\Lambda$ of a randomly chosen person has a Gamma distribution with the $\Gamma(2, 1)$-density function $f_\Lambda(\lambda) = \lambda e^{−\lambda}$, $(\lambda > 0)$. Find the expected value
of $\Lambda$ for a policyholder having $x$ accidents this year $(x = 0, 1, 2 \ldots)$?

Not quite sure how to start this, I was thinking it's $\mathbb E[\Lambda|X=x]$, but I can't find any documentation on how conditional expectation is solved when the distributions aren't both discrete or both continuous.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142036/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [Bayes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_theorem#Random_variables) has forms for all three cases of continuous variables being involved. In this case, we use the first form:
$$f_{\Lambda}(\lambda \mid X = x) = \frac{\Pr[X = x \mid \Lambda = \lambda] f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)}{\Pr[X = x]}.$$
In this expression,

- $\Pr[X=x \mid \Lambda=\lambda]$ is just the probability that a $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ customer will have $x$ accidents,
- $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)$ is the density function you're given, and
- $\Pr[X=x]$ is the constant factor we need to divide by to make $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda \mid X = x)$ integrate to $1$.

Once you know $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda \mid X = x)$, you can find the expected value of $(\Lambda \mid X=x)$ just as you would with any other density function.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! Solving for the constant to make sure it integrates to 1 I get $\frac{x+1}{2^{x+2}}$, to make it the density of a $Gamma(x+2,2)$ function. So the expected value would be $\frac{x+2}{2}$ then right? Or have I gone wrong somewhere

Comment: That's what I get for the expected value, too. (Either I misunderstand you, or your Poisson distribution calculation is slightly off; you should get an $x!$ from there, and only a $\frac{x+1}{2^{x+2}}$ from the denominator - but either way, it's an error that fixes itself when you make $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda \mid X=x)$ integrate to $1$.)