# Find $\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mid X=n],~\text{where}~ X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda), \lambda \sim \Gamma(a,b).$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ where $\lambda \sim \Gamma(a,b)$. Find $$\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mid X=n].$$

Thanks to StubbornAtom hint I have solved this problem.

**Solution:**

By definition:
$$\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mid X=n] = \frac{\mathbb E\left[\lambda\mathbf1_{X=n}\right]}{\mathbb P(X=n)}.$$

So we have to find distribution of random variable $X$ and $\mathbb E\left[\lambda\mathbf1_{X=n}\right].$ Let's start by finding distribution of $X$. We have

\begin{align} 
P(X=n) &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbf1_{X=n} \mid \lambda]] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X=n \mid \lambda = x) \mu_{\lambda}(dx) 
\\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)}}x^{a-1}e^{-bx}dx 
\\ &= \frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)}n!}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x(1+b)}x^{n+a-1}dx 
\end{align} 
substitut $t=x(1+b)$
\begin{align}
&\frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)}n!}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\big(\frac{t}{1+b}\big)^{n+a-1}\frac{1}{1+b}dt = \frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)}n!} \frac{\Gamma{(n+a)}}{(1+b)^{n+a}} 
\\ &= \frac{b^a}{a!n!} \frac{a(a+n-1)!}{(1+b)^{n+a}} = \frac{(a+n-1)!}{(a-1)!n!}\big(\frac{b}{b+1}\big)^{a}\big(1-\frac{b}{b+1}\big)^{n} 
\\ &= {{n+a-1}\choose{n}}\big(\frac{b}{b+1}\big)^{a}\big(1-\frac{b}{b+1}\big)^{n}.
\end{align}

Now

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mathbf1_{X=n}]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mathbf1_{X=n}\mid \lambda]]
\\&=\mathbb{E}[\lambda\mathbb{E}[\mathbf1_{X=n}\mid \lambda]]
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)}}x^{a-1}e^{-bx}dx 
\\&= \frac{b^a}{\Gamma{(a)n!}}\frac{\Gamma{(n+a+1)}}{(b+1)^{n+a+1}}
\\& = \frac{(a+n)!}{(a-1)!n!}\frac{b^a}{(b+1)^{n+a+1}}.
\end{align}
Hence

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\lambda \mid X=n] &= \frac{\mathbb E\left[\lambda\mathbf1_{X=n}\right]}{\mathbb P(X=n)}
\\ &= \frac{(a+n)!}{(a-1)!n!}\frac{b^a}{(b+1)^{n+a+1}}\frac{(a-1)!n!}{(a+n-1)!}\frac{(b+1)^{n+a}}{b^a}  
\\ &= \frac{a+n}{b+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe start by writing $E[\lambda | X = n ] = \frac{E[\lambda 1_{X = n}]}{P(X=n)}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2203316/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142036/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given that the random variable $X$ conditioned on the random variable $\Lambda$ has a Poisson distribution where $\Lambda$ itself has a Gamma distribution.

As mentioned in comments, you have by definition $$\mathbb E\left[\Lambda\mid X=n\right]=\frac{\mathbb E\left[\Lambda\mathbf1_{X=n}\right]}{\mathbb P(X=n)}$$

Now you can use the law of total expectation:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\Lambda \mathbf1_{X=n}\right]&=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[\Lambda \mathbf1_{X=n}\mid \Lambda\right]\right]
\\&=\mathbb E\left[\Lambda\mathbb E\left[ \mathbf1_{X=n}\mid \Lambda\right]\right]
\\&=\cdots
\end{align}