# Conditional Expected Value Problem involving Poisson and Gamma distributions

Tags: probability, expected-value

The question is

> An insurance company supposes that the number of accidents that each of its policyholders will have this year is Poisson distributed, with a mean depending on the policyholder: the Poisson mean $\Lambda$ of a randomly chosen person has a Gamma distribution with the $\Gamma(2, 1)$-density function $f_\Lambda(\lambda) = \lambda{e^{-\lambda}} $ ($\lambda > 0$). Find the expected value of $\Lambda$ for a policyholder having $x$ accidents this year ($x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$)

I am very unsure of how to solve this problem. I know that we need to solve for $E(\Lambda\mid X=x).$ I am pretty sure, but not sure what comes after this.

Comment: Your notation is confusing and I'm not sure what your actual question is. Here is a tutorial on how to use MathJax to format equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Math1000 I have updated the problem to where I saw the issues

Comment: @Math1000 The question is to find the expected value of $\Lambda$ for a policyholder having x accidents this year where x = 0,1,2,3,...

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322314/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142036/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2203316/321264

Answer (score 0):

For any fixed $x=1,2,3,\ldots$
$$
\mathbb E(\Lambda\mid X=x) = \int_0^\infty \lambda\cdot f_{\Lambda\mid X}(\lambda\mid x)\, d\lambda
$$
is the expected value of a random variable with conditional pdf 
$$
f_{\Lambda\mid X}(\lambda\mid x) \propto f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)\cdot f_{X\mid \Lambda}(x\mid \lambda).
$$
Here the second term is the pmf since $X$ is discrete r.v.
$$
f_{X\mid \Lambda}(x\mid \lambda) = \mathbb P(X=x \mid \Lambda=\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}
$$
and therefore
$$
f_{\Lambda\mid X}(\lambda\mid x) \propto f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)\cdot f_{X\mid \Lambda}(x\mid \lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}\propto \color{red}{\lambda^{x+1} e^{-2\lambda}}.
$$
So conditional distribution of $\Lambda$ given $X=x$ is $\Gamma(2,x+2)$. Indeed, the pdf of $\Gamma(2,x+2)$ is 
$$
\gamma_{2,x+2}(\lambda) = c\cdot \color{red}{\lambda^{x+2-1}e^{-2\lambda}} 
$$
This is exactly the pdf that we got.

The expected value this distributon is $\frac{x+2}{2}$. So the answer is
$$
\mathbb E(\Lambda\mid X=x) = \frac{x+2}{2}.
$$

Comment: how do you know that the $\Gamma$ is (2, x+2)? When in the problem is says $\Gamma$(2,1)

Comment: Also, What does the $\alpha$ mean? or alpha looking symbol?

Comment: It is not $\alpha$, it is a symbol 'proportional to': $f \propto g$ means that the function $f$ equals to $c\cdot g$ where $c$ is the normalizing constant.

Comment: @ttucker34 If write conditional pdf completely, $$f_{\Lambda|X}(\lambda|x) =\frac{f_\Lambda(\lambda)f_{X|\Lambda}(x|\lambda)}{f_X(x)}$$ The denominator here does not depend on the unique variable $\lambda$ and therefore it is suitable to write $f_{\Lambda|X}(\lambda|x) $ is proportional (up to a constant) to a numerator.